# Filter results of a $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a lookup that is working. However, I need to filter the results with a $match or something similar. The local collection has a field called "clinic_id". The from collection has a field called branchId. I need to ensure that these fields are filtered. Basically only results with branchId of "1" and clinic_id of "1".

```
 {
 $lookup:
 {
   from: "chatrooms",
   localField: "userId",
   foreignField: "user.id",
   as: "merged"
 }
}
```

I've tried to use $match and $unwind but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lookup you can use `$match` to apply the conditions in the same query

```
{
    $lookup:
        {
           from: "chatrooms",
           localField: "userId",
           foreignField: "user.id",
           as: "merged"
        }
},{
    $match: {
              "merged.branchId" : "1",
              "clinic_id" : "1"
            }
}
```

you can also check the local collection `clinic_id` first and then the branchId after lookup: ( This will work faster as lookup time will be less)

```
{
    $match: {
              "clinic_id" : "1"
            }
},
{
    $lookup:
        {
           from: "chatrooms",
           localField: "userId",
           foreignField: "user.id",
           as: "merged"
        }
},
{
    $match: {
              "merged.branchId" : "1"
            }
}
```